# Reciprocating motion in alternating tracks

Tags: mechanical-engineering, linear-motion

I’m trying to find a solution for a simple feeder mechanism where a spring-loaded ”piston” gets pushed in a linear motion, and then on the way back it switches to parallel track, enabling it to be pushed on that parallel track every other push. The goal is to implement the mechanism in a hand tool, so no other force except the one it gets from springing back is allowed. Here’s an animation of what I’m thinking.
[image: alternating mechanism]

I found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yue66-XHdX8) which basically is what I want to achieve, but there must be more simple way for this application (hand tool).

Comment: Standard solutions are Fourbars and Cams (generally beginners think in terms of cams but here a four are probably what one wants to start with)

Answer (score 0):

A simple rotating cylindrical cam might do the trick.

[image]

*Figure 1. Cylindrical cam with two followers. Drive shaft, cam follower guides and springs not shown.*

If the action *must* be performed by a push action then the classic ballpoint pen rotating click-mechanism could drive the cam or *be* the cam.

Comment: Thank you for the input. Yes, the action must be performed by a push action. A rotating cam may work. Ideally I would like to avoid all rotating movements due to the space requirements it needs, so I will try to see if there is any sliding mechanism that achieves the same result